# Sound is too fast in chrome using Flash player

Tags: sound, google-chrome, flash, pulseaudio, vlc

I have NPAPI flash player disabled and everything runs fine until I use VLC player.

So, the thing is: I open Chrome, then VLC, watch the movie there (not necessary till the end), stop it and then open flash audio player. The audio is faster than normal. This effect persists until I logout or restart pulseaudio (`pulseaudio -k`).

So, this is definitely a bug. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in Chrome as well, just noticed it recently, was fine before. I found that disabling the VLC Multimedia Plugin in Chrome (chrome://plugins) solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I found with Google Chrome is to disable PepperFlash in chrome://plugins and enable Shockwave Flash. That took care of the sound issue. So if you can do without PepperFlash, that might fix it for you.

For what it's worth, I'm using the adobe-flashplugin from the partner repository, not the flashplugin-installer. I understand (from a page on askubuntu) that adobe-flashplugin is better for 64-bit systems.

Comment: Well, Shockwave flash is crappy on multi-monitor configurations, so I can't use it. But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with PepperFlash not checking or caring what Pulseaudio's default sample rate is. One can change Pulseaudio's sample rate to 48000, then restart Pulseaudio/Chrome.

Un-comment default-sample-rate and change it to 48000:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

;default-sample-rate = 44100

default-sample-rate = 48000
```

Read more about the [Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=229918)